# Fade in background image on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein

I want to load one of the random background image by using jquery. Below is the script I am using and it shows random background on refresh but without fadeIn effect. How can I create fadeIn effect onload. Note: I don't want to cycle random images.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var images = ['01.jpg', '02.jpg', '03.jpg', '04.jpg', '05.jpg', '06.jpg', '07.jpg', '08.jpg', '09.jpg', '10.jpg'];

  $('.about').css({'background-image': 'url(../img/bg/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
  ('.about').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: You add another dollarsign, and you hide the element before you try to fade it in

Comment: Also the image may not be loaded when the element is already faded in. Especially when the image is large.

Comment: I added dollarsign but it is still now working.

Comment: How can I ensure that background image is loaded before fadein effect?

Comment: Preload it before you attach it to the `about` and put a onload on the image loader. If the image has loaded then render background on the about element and fade in

Comment: Please can create a fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var images = ['http://funmozar.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Beautiful-Yellow-Birds-06.jpg', 'http://petblaster.com/images/Birdwall.jpg', 'http://www.nscblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/birds-314989.jpg'];

  var url = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){
    $('.about').css({'background-image': 'url('+url+')', 'background-size' : 'contain'});
    $('.about').fadeIn(1000);
  }
  img.src = url;
  
  
});
```

```css
.about{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="about"></div>
```

This will preload the image using `new Image`. An `onload` is attached. When he onload fires it will set the background to the `.about` div and fade it in.

I've changed the urls to actually show some results.